# Permission denied when 'mongod' command is run after successful installation

Tags: macos, mongodb

I successfully installed mongodb, then I get this error after running the `mongod` command:

> 2015-08-21T20:48:25.862+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 98 Unable to create/open lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating
>   2015-08-21T20:48:25.889+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100

I have even done this and got this result:

```
ls -ld /data/db/
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel  68 Aug 21 20:45 /data/db/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give read write permission to db data folder and reopen your terminal and then try mongod. Good luck.

Comment: Probably fixing the *ownership* of the database is a better fix